# libsndfile on iOS

Tags: c++, c, ios, libsndfile

Nowdays I met a strange link problem when I try to use `libsndfile` on `iOS`:

I've compiled `libsndfile` on `MACOSX 10.6.8` and it passed all the checks. But when I added it to the Xcode and tried to compile it on `iOS`, I got these link warning and errors:

```
ld: warning: in /Users/chencyz/Desktop/Development/SDK/libsndfile/lib/libsndfile.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols:
  "_sf_close", referenced from:
      SndfileHandle::SNDFILE_ref::~SNDFILE_ref()in AudioReader.o
  "_sf_error", referenced from:
      SndfileHandle::error() const in AudioReader.o
  "_sf_open", referenced from:
      SndfileHandle::SndfileHandle(char const*, int, int, int, int)in AudioReader.o
  "_sf_read_float", referenced from:
      SndfileHandle::read(float*, long long)in AudioReader.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

`AudioReader` is just a simple class which uses the program API of `libsndfile`.

Does anyone knows something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you did not recompile the library for iOS, you seem to be trying to link against the i386 version of the library. The first line in the error message you pasted is pretty clear about it.

iOS runs on ARM processors, so you need to build the library for ARM.

Comment: Thanks :) Now I compile the libsndfile into i386 version and the link problem is gone,but there is another problem:

Comment: Since libsndfile depends on the libogg, libvorbis and libflac, I have to compile all of them before compile libsndfile, but when I compile them all, I find that libsndfile.a doesn't include the libogg.a,libvorbis.a(and other) and libflac.a, so if I want to use libsndfile in the project, I have to add them all ......

Comment: I'm not so sure about this, do you know something about it?

Comment: Sounds like a problem in your Makefile or project file. Also note that you said you build for i386, that is not correct, iOS executables are built for the ARM processor.

Comment: Now I just can build the library into i386 version, but when I try to build the library into armv6 version, I met a lot problem ... like missing some C base headers ...

Comment: I can't without any more details, why don't you write another question?